# Mousepad in Xubuntu 13.04 prints unwanted line numbers

Tags: 13.04, printing, xfce4

Mousepad is the standard editor in Xubuntu 13.04. If used for printing a file it always prints line numbers, even if the option is switched off in the print dialog. What to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I just published a fixed build for Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy). Feel free to grab it if you don't want to wait for the official fix:

https://launchpad.net/~foresto/+archive/ubuntutweaks/

Here are the relevant bug reports:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9813

https://bugs.launchpad.net/mousepad/+bug/1267958